# d3 - get data bound with element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, javascript-databinding

The following snippet add d3.geo.circle() object as path element in an svg element. The code is:

```
    var g = svg.append("g");
    var circles = g.selectAll("path.circle");
    var circle = d3.geo.circle();
    circles = circles.data(d3.values(data));
    circles
        .enter()
        .append("path");
        .datum(function(d) {
            return circle
                .origin([d.lon, d.lat])
                .angle(0.2)();
        })
        .attr("class", "circle")
        .attr("d", path);
```

Now, I want to add say, a mouseOver event on these circles, which will log(prints) latitude-longitude information, I cannot access like:

```
     g.selectAll('path.circle')
     .on("mouseover", function(d,i) { 
         console.log(d.lat + "-" + d.lon);
     });
```

I understand that the 'd' represents the d3.geo.circle object, but I could not figure out how to reach the data[i]?

Comment: It looks like you're binding the circle generator as the data to the element. You shouldn't need the additional `.datum()` if you move that part into the definition of `d`.

Comment: @lars, can you please explain how to move that part into definition of d. I am a bit hazy on this.

Comment: Isn't this just `circles.enter().append("path").attr("d", function(d,i){ return circle.origin[d.lon, d.lat]).angle(0.2)();});`

Comment: @Mark is right -- and then just pass all of that with `d` to `path`.

Comment: @Mark, I tried this code, but now there are no circles at all. 

circles
                .attr("class", "circle")
                .attr("d", function(d) {
                    return circle
                        .origin([d.lon, d.lat])
                        .angle(0.2)();
                })
                .style("fill", "yellow")
                .on("mouseover", airportMouseOver)
                .on("mouseout", airportMouseOut);
Can you please explain what Lars meant by "pass all of that with d to path"?

Comment: I am not fully thorough with the underlying concept here. Can you please help me understand the solution.

Comment: finally I looked into the documentation much carefully and tried this and got it worked. Thanks for the help:
            circles
                .attr("class", "circle")
                .attr("d", function(d) {
                    return path(circle
                        .origin([d.lon, d.lat])
                        .angle(0.2)());
                })
                .style("fill", "yellow")
                .on("mouseover", airportMouseOver)
                .on("mouseout", airportMouseOut);